# Mass, time and length are measured with 5% accuracy each, what will be the total accuracy in torque?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, measurements, units, error-analysis

I don't understand the solution of the above question, the solution i know is :-

Accuracy in torque = [M%] + [2 × L%] + [2 × T%]

Which will be equal to 25%

I dont understand why 2 was multiplied to L% and T%?

Comment: Do you understand what the dimensions of torque are? In other words, how many powers of mass, length, and time?

Comment: Are you sure that it is multiplication and not exponentiation? Check SI base units for torque. Hint, τ = r × F, F = m*a. Keep substituting until you can no longer break each unit into SI base units.

Comment: @Ghoster yes obviously it is [(ML²)/T²] please note that i dont have the sign of -2 power so i put the time in denominator, now can you please answer my intial question :)

Comment: @Omnitragedy yes i am sure it is multiplication and both question and answer are valid as they have appeared in an important entrance exam, and also i know how to write the dimensional formula of torque, what i want to know is  why are we multiplying 2 to Time and length? :)

Comment: When $L$ and $T$ are uncertain by 5%, $L^2$ and $T^{-2}$ are uncertain by about 10%. (What are $(1.05)^2$ and $(1.05)^{-2}$?)

Comment: *obviously it is…* If it is obvious, and if you noticed that the exponents are very similar to the accuracy factors, then you should have mentioned all this.

Comment: *now can you please answer my intial question* You should never expect that someone who simply comments is necessarily going to answer. That’s not how the site works. (I was expecting my first hint to help you answer it *yourself.*) Also, homework-like questions such as this generally get closed, not answered or even hinted.

Comment: *please note that i dont have the sign of -2 power* Yes, you do. You should be using MathJax to write all math, both in questions and in comments. A link to a tutorial is provided in step 1 of the instructions when you ask a question. Your math will then be textbook-quality!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a quantity A is measured with an accuracy $\delta A$, then from the reported value $\bar{A}$ we find that the actual value of $A$ is as follows:
$$\bar{A}-\delta A<A<\bar{A}+\delta A\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$
Sometimes written $A=\bar{A}\pm \delta A$.

Now we assume that the physical quantity A is a function of two other quantities $B$ and $C$: $A=f(B,C)$. Taking into account the accuracy in measuring $B$ and $C$, i.e. $\delta B$ and $\delta C$, you can calculate $\delta A$
$$\delta A=\, \frac{\partial f}{\partial B}\bigg|_{B=\bar{B},C=\bar{C}}\delta B+\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}\bigg|_{B=\bar{B},C=\bar{C}}\delta C$$
Note, however, that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial B}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}$ can be positive or negative. Take advantage of the fact that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial B}\delta B+\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}\delta C\le \big|\frac{\partial f}{\partial B}\big|\delta B+\big|\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}\big|\delta C, $$
we can write inequality $(1)$ as
$$1-\frac{\big|\frac{\partial f}{\partial B}\big|\delta B+\big|\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}\big|\delta C}{ f(\bar{B},\bar{C})}< \frac{A}{f(\bar{B},\bar{C})}<1+\underbrace{\frac{\big|\frac{\partial f}{\partial B}\big|\delta B+\big|\frac {\partial f}{\partial C}\big|\delta C}{f(\bar{B},\bar{C})}}_{\text{accuracy}}$$

In your case, $A\equiv \frac{M L^2 }{T^2}$ so the accuracy is
$$\frac{|L^2 T^{-2}|\,\delta M+|M (2L) T^{-2}|\,\delta L+|M L^2 (-2 T^{-3 }) |\,\delta T}{M L^2 T^{-2}}\\
= \frac{\delta M}{M}+2 \frac{\delta L}{L}+2 \frac{\delta T}{T}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a surprisingly pretty approach!